# EasyDNNNews Calendar iCal Imports Major Error / Makes Entire Site Unresponsive

Tags: dotnetnuke

Currently using EasyDNNnews to for a number of items on a website.  Utilizing the Calendar, we're running into a major issue when it comes to importing an iCal feed from an external source.  EasyDNN Support has been rather unhelpful - currently frustrated and not sure how to proceed:

Running EVOQ Content v. 09.01.00
EasyDNN News: 8.5

Issue: We go to the RSS Import screen, select "iCalendar Import" as the Feed type, and set all other settings.

Schedule this to happen once a day at 3am.  When scheduler runs, it seems to not work and makes the entire site non-responsive.  Has anyone run into any issues with the iCalendar importing on EasyDNN?

Comment: I think you should ask the developer about this using the Helpdesk Ticket System at the [DNN store](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/). It's the most sold news module and it probably has good support.

Comment: have you check the logs? it's inside [Dnn folder]/Portals/_default/logs